# How to use CupertinoTimerPicker in AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, showdialog, flutter-cupertino, flutter-alertdialog

When I use CupertinoTimerPicker in AlertDialog I'm Getting LayoutBuilder Error.
How can I use CupertinoTimerPicker in AlertDialog?

This is my code:

```
showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                content: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                    onTimerDurationChanged: (value) {}

                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
          },
        );
```

Error Message

```
throw FlutterError(
      'LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.\n'
      'Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require running the layout '
      'callback speculatively, which might mutate the live render object tree.',
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this and also the output in image below

```
Duration selectedValue;

Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(40),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      CupertinoButton(
        child: Text("Show Picker"),
        onPressed: (){
          showTimerPicker();
        },
      ),
      Material(
        child: Text(
          "$selectedValue",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]
  ),
),

void showTimerPicker() {
  showCupertinoModalPopup(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext builder) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.25,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
          initialTimerDuration: Duration(hours:0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0),
          onTimerDurationChanged: (value) {
            selectedValue = value;
            setState(() {});
          },
        )
      );
    }
  );
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this method where you have a button and click on it

```
void showTimerPicker() {
showCupertinoModalPopup(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext builder) {
      return Container(
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .copyWith()
              .size
              .height * 0.25,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
            initialTimerDuration: Duration(hours:0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0);
            onTimerDurationChanged: (value) {
              selectedValue = value;
              setState(() {

              });
            },
          )
      );
    }
);
```

}